# Why is it acceptable to use the "http" scheme for OAuth Loopback interface redirect URIs?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

In section 8.3 of the OAuth IETF RFC: "Loopback Redirect Considerations" it states:

"Loopback interface redirect URIs use the http scheme (i.e., without TLS). This is acceptable for loopback interface redirect URIs as the HTTP request never leaves the device."

Why is https not necessary for security here? I realize using PKCE mitigates some of the concerns of URI interception, but I'm not sure I fully understand how the redirect is received by the client on the loopback interface.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If traffic on your own machine can be intercepted, basically 'all is lost'. It's two processes communicating, and anything with the privilege to read that would be able to do a lot more.

The PKCE mitigations exists mainly because on modern phone OS's, applications can effectively 'take over' certain uri with specific schemes, and unlike with DNS where there was a perfectly good system of ownership, Mobile OS vendors created a vulnerability by introducing a new unmanaged namespace.

So, if my redirect starts with `my-app://`, there's nothing stopping another application from also registering that schema and be launched with the oauth2 authorization code.

If this makes you think companies like Apple have messed up here, you would definitely right.

Comment: Briefly and to the point! Thanks